# `bulk_edit_custom_box` mess the input fields

Tags: wp-list-table, bulk

I'm trying to create a bulk-edit plugin. Here is how Wordpress builk edit form looks by default:

[image: default]

Than I add the following code:

```
add_action( 'bulk_edit_custom_box', 'my_bulk_edit_custom_box', 10, 2 );
function my_bulk_edit_custom_box( $column_name, $post_type ) {  
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
        <label class="inline-edit-<?php echo $column_name; ?>">
            <span class="title">Custom</span>
            <select class="<?php echo $column_name; ?>" name="<?php echo $column_name; ?>">
                <option value="-1"><?php _e( '&mdash; No Change &mdash;' ); ?></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
```

And the mystery is that form now looks like that:

[image: custom]

The question is why field "Tags" jumps down? And is there is a way prevent tags input box from moving anywhere?

Comment: Have you added any CSS? This seems more like a CSS issue. Try just for testing to place one `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before the `<fieldset>`.

Comment: No, I haven't added any CSS. As far as I can see in an inspector, Dom was modified, not CSS